# List manipulation in JavaScript to make it a JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I Have the following list:

```
0: "Ownership"
1: "Skills<br>Development"
2: "Socio-Economic<br>Development"
3: "Board Participation"
4: "Employee Structure"
5: "Preferential Procurement"
6: "Enterprise Development"
7: "Supplier Development"
```

and I would like to add items to it to make each item in the list like this :

```
[{
    "label": "Ownership",
    "cleanTarget": 3,
    "populateTarget": 3
  },
  {
    "label": "Skills<br>Development",
    "cleanTarget": 3,
    "populateTarget": 3
  },
  {
    "label": "Supplier Development",
    "cleanTarget": 3,
    "populateTarget": 3
  }
]
```

And so on, I have tried the following:

```
var data = {
  'label': testList,
  'cleanTarget': DefaultItem,
  'populateTarget': DefaultItem
};

console.log(data);
```

But my output doesnt look correct, it shows like this:

```
cleanTarget: 3
label: Array(8)
  0: "Ownership"
  1: "Skills<br>Development"
  2: "Socio-Economic<br>Development"
  3: "Board Participation"
  4: "Employee Structure"
  5: "Preferential Procurement"
  6: "Enterprise Development"
  7: "Supplier Development'
populateTarget: 3
```

Comment: Your code is doing no transformation on the original array. Assuming the original source is an array, you can use `array.map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map` as follows.

```js
const input = [
  "Ownership",
  "Skills<br>Development",
  "Socio-Economic<br>Development",
  "Board Participation",
  "Employee Structure",
  "Preferential Procurement",
  "Enterprise Development",
  "Supplier Development"
];

const DefaultItem = 3;
const output = input.map((item) => ({
  'label': item,
  'cleanTarget': DefaultItem,
  'populateTarget':DefaultItem
}));
console.log(output);
```